# Blender collision export primitives issue

Tags: export, physics

I have just started learning blender, and I am having trouble exporting a few very basic collision shapes. I would appreciate any pointers where I might be going wrong

I exported to .bullet using PhysicsConstraints.exportBulletFile

1. Cones are exported perfectly (verified by recreating programmatically)

2. Cylinders are exported with the wrong scale

3. Boxes are exported with correct position but AABB only wraps original unrotated shape

I have a very simple Blender scene with two cylinders, a cone and a box:
[image: blender scene]
[image: scene when imported to bullet]

In Blender:
All have "Add Active" and are green when selected

All have radius = 1.0

All have "Rigid Body"

All have "Collision Bounds" ticked with the correct shape selected

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try `Ctrl-A` (Apply transform menu) -> `Scale` for the cylinder?

Comment: Thanks, this was part of it. The origin location and rotation value was also important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that blender .bullet export (for primitives) does not export correctly if:

1. “Apply Object Transform” for Location or Rotation is performed. This is not reversible quickly

2. The “origin” is not at the object bounds center (i.e. 1a was performed, location reset to 0)

3. Rotation in blender != value you want (i.e. 1a was performed, rotation reset to 0)

4. Scale in blender != 1.0 (i.e. 1a for Scale was NOT performed)

5. Something moved in the scene before the script ran